# Getting 401 error without any message while authorizing dotnet core web api with keycloack

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, authorization, keycloak, openid-connect

I was setting authentication and authorization for my dotnet core application (3.1 version). I set up a keycloak server as my identity provider. I got a JWT token from keycloak and i used it while calling my api method. I am always getting 401 error. I have checked almost all the Keycloak configurations and i am not able to find the issue.

My JWT token is

```
eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJza0dldkJuZnhieWlCSF9sOC1ZSEpxVnk2bm8yV3c0eG14a0xjeVlvMXRzIn0.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.gFjqPSmyXvk78OhbPJ853upCHIHZdsAsjT1Psc7pzBqv30unH0EyCk3chTK0_87J-5bH2QAEyShKc0QVENMEL2PEhIKvgI7hdqT7oBKiTu3Ux2U5c2KbL9Dbism7nhr9FidrrkxtOsJUyR9hbZCGLnrmoHJEkNMvp3usS4HO1AxwaCSKUVXyNy3FmQJnY_R33IdSaiKsaLCJg57SIak1SexPnlUyFT6_yvbyKLjgpuL3Uk5TasQ3A8GVM2RRGVZa-s9L75rsFflkmRtAvCQca3QCRq8vHl929q6yy2TSrNlVLCeQxdK3Yapk-k_KSFS0dkoCgSQ3F5oGOECxPw-pBg
```

My Startup.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Fts.App.Definitions;
using Fts.App.Services;
using Fts.Data.Defnitions;
using Fts.Data.Repository;
using Lbs.FtsClient;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace Fts.Api
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup()
        {
            Configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").Build();
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

            }).AddJwtBearer("Bearer",o =>
            {
                o.Authority = Configuration["Jwt:Authority"];
                o.Audience = Configuration["Jwt:Audience"];
                o.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

                o.Events = new JwtBearerEvents()
                {
                    OnAuthenticationFailed = c =>
                    {
                        c.NoResult();

                        c.Response.StatusCode = 500;
                        c.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";

                        return c.Response.WriteAsync(c.Exception.ToString());
                    }
                };
            });
            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("apiadmin", policy => policy.RequireClaim("fts-rules", "[fts_admin]"));
            });

            services.AddTransient<IUserRepository, UserRepositiry>();
            services.AddTransient<IDbAccess, DbAccess>();
            services.AddTransient<ISiteRepository, SiteRepository>();
            services.AddTransient<IAssetRepository, AssetRepository>();
            services.AddTransient<IAssetService, AssetService>();
            services.AddTransient<IFtsWebService, FtsWebService>();
            services.AddControllers();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            app.UseCors(builder =>
                    builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200").AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader());

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I added following in my controller.

```
[Authorize(Roles = "apiadmin")]
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
```

Please help on this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add authentication middleware to your web api application , otherwise JWT bearer authentication won't work :

```
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();  <-- add this line 
app.UseAuthorization();
```